# Copy IIS 6 to IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a Windows Server 2003 that is running IIS 6 with several web sites and I need to copy the web sites to a Windows Server 2008 server running IIS 7.5.  Is there anyway to copy the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) install it in the IIS 7.5 and you can sync all the server configuration, sites, etc, to the new server.
Here is an example:
http://www.iishacks.com/2008/10/07/migrating-websites-from-iis6-to-iis7/